# What does __tg_promote do in tgmath.h

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, math.h, tgmath

I'm looking at `tgmath.h` and trying to understand exactly how it selects the correct function based on the size of the input value.

The special sauce seems to be this `__tg_promote` macro but the deeper I dig the deeper this puzzle gets. Does anyone have a short answer to what `__tg_promote` actually does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In clang's implementation of `tgmath.h` it appears that `__tg_promote` is in fact a *function*, and not a macro. The definition can be found [here](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/tgmath_8h_source.html).

```
typedef void _Argument_type_is_not_arithmetic;
static _Argument_type_is_not_arithmetic __tg_promote(...)
  __attribute__((__unavailable__,__overloadable__));
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(int);
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(unsigned int);
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(long);
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(unsigned long);
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(long long);
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(unsigned long long);
static float                _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(float);
static double               _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(double);
static long double          _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(long double);
static float _Complex       _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(float _Complex);
static double _Complex      _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(double _Complex);
static long double _Complex _TG_ATTRSp __tg_promote(long double _Complex);
```

It's a function with multiple overloads (not allowed in C in general) and no definition, which is fine because it's never actually called! `__tg_promote` is only used to determine the type that a numeric type should be promoted to. (Integral types to `double`; floating point types to themselves.) This is clear when you look at the next few macros:

```
#define __tg_promote1(__x)           (__typeof__(__tg_promote(__x)))
#define __tg_promote2(__x, __y)      (__typeof__(__tg_promote(__x) + \
                                                 __tg_promote(__y)))
#define __tg_promote3(__x, __y, __z) (__typeof__(__tg_promote(__x) + \
                                                 __tg_promote(__y) + \
                                                 __tg_promote(__z)))
```

The `__tg_promote` function isn't being called because it occurs inside the compiler-specific `__typeof__` macro. The `__tg_promote1` macro simply expands to the *promoted type* of its argument, within parentheses. `__tg_promote2` expands to the type (again parenthesis-enclosed) that would result if two values of the promoted types of its arguments were added. So for example, `__tg_promote2(0.0f, 0)` would be `(double)`, since adding a `float` and a `double` (result of promoting `int`) gives a `double`. `__tg_promote3` is similar.

The remainder of the header consists of overloaded definitions of functions that delegate to the respective ordinary C functions:

```
// atan2

static float
    _TG_ATTRS
    __tg_atan2(float __x, float __y) {return atan2f(__x, __y);}

static double
    _TG_ATTRS
    __tg_atan2(double __x, double __y) {return atan2(__x, __y);}

static long double
    _TG_ATTRS
    __tg_atan2(long double __x, long double __y) {return atan2l(__x, __y);}
```

In order to be able to call, say, `atan2(1.0f, 1)` we need to be able to delegate to `__tg_atan2(double, double)`. This is where `__tg_promote2` comes in to determine that when we have one `float` argument and one `int` argument, both should be converted to `double`:

```
#define atan2(__x, __y) __tg_atan2(__tg_promote2((__x), (__y))(__x), \
                                   __tg_promote2((__x), (__y))(__y))
```

So in this case `__tg_promote2((__x), (__y))` expands to `(double)` and we get `__tg_atan2((double)(__x), (double)(__y))`, which is exactly what we want.